# Revert to initial active tab when mouse leaves area, or using JS in Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I want to revert back to the initially active tab when the user moves the mouse away from the menu.

I have a left top-level menu that changes the active tab on hover, using data-options="is_hover:true"

When hovering over any of the tabs, it displays the second-level menu in place of the main content (which is displayed in a tab, which is displayed by default on page load).

I want the default content tab to display whenever the mouse leaves the 1st or 2nd level menu area.

Alternatively, I can make other elements detect the mouse hover and use JS to command the initial tag to be active. However I cannot find any documentation on what the JS should say, eg:

```
$( ".detect" ).hover(function() {
    $( SET TAB1 TO ACTIVE PLEASE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I did was put the default content out of the tab an into its own div (where the tabs would go).

I then made none of the tabs active by default in CSS.

Then I used JS to deactivate any active tabs on hover of any element with class "detect":

```
$( ".detect" ).hover(function() {
$(".content.active").removeClass( "active" );
$("li.active").removeClass( "active" );
});
```